# Слишком большой отступ между текстами, как его сделать меньше.html css

Tags: html, css, текст

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня тут выходит слишком большой отступ, писал маржины и падинги, а они ничего не меняли. Помогите, как сделать его меньше?

```css
/* ИНТРО САЙТА*/

.container_intro {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.intro {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;

    background: url(../Trademine/images/фон\ интро.png) center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.intro_name {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

.int_name {
    color: #439f3c;
    font-weight: 800;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.info_int {
    color: black;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
    <div class="intro">
        <div class="container_intro">
            <div class="intro_name">
                <h1 class="int_name">TRADEMine</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="intro_info">
                <p class="info_int">Торговая площадка Minecraft ценностей, где вы можете безопасно                         приобрести любой товар. Мы имеем уникальную систему сделок, где нельзя остаться обманутым.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: **Возможно** вся проблема из-за шрифта. Если никак не получается уменьшить расстояние, попробуйте подобрать отрицательный `margin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Добавь обнуляющий стиль, например

```
/* Указываем box sizing */
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* Убираем внутренние отступы */
ul[class],
ol[class] {
  padding: 0;
}
/* Убираем внешние отступы */
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
p,
ul[class],
ol[class],
li,
figure,
figcaption,
blockquote,
dl,
dd {
  margin: 0;
}
/* Удаляем стандартную стилизацию для всех ul и il, у которых есть атрибут class*/
ul[class],
ol[class] {
  list-style: none;
}
/* Элементы a, у которых нет класса, сбрасываем до дефолтных стилей */
a:not([class]) {
  text-decoration-skip-ink: auto;
}
/* Наследуем шрифты для инпутов и кнопок */
input,
button,
textarea,
select {
  font: inherit;
}
```

2. Уменьши margin-top у .int_name